# How to INSERT row in another database/schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql, schema, insert

Let's say I have the following database/schema setup with the following tables:

```
    SCHEMA_1 (default):
        TABLE_1

    SCHEMA_2:
        TABLE_2
```

How do I insert rows in another schema's table? The following does not seem to work:

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (...) VALUES(...)
```

How is it possible to insert rows in another another schema?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM schema_2.TABLE_2` ,  `INSERT INTO schema_2.TABLE_2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fully qualify the table name:

```
insert into SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2 values( ... );
```

Comment: I tried that but I get the error message that "SCHEMA_1.SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2" does not exist.

Comment: SCHEMA_1.SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2 ? What exactly did you type to do the insert?

Comment: Sorry now I understand, I used ` around the table: INSERT INTO `SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2` (...) VALUES(...). Did not know that it made a difference.

Comment: Note that for some reason the `-sign is not shown around SCHEME_2.TABLE_2 in my above comment.

Comment: @Andy: You used `INSERT INTO \`schema2.table2\` VALUES ...`. You should either remove those (as in Phil's answer) or: `INSERT INTO \`schema2\`.\`table2\` VALUES ...` (if necessary to use backquotes). The dot `.` should not be inside the quotes :)

Comment: does UPDATE statement works too ?

Answer (score 2):

It should be fully qualified table name means DatabaseName.TableName
In your case it will be

```
Insert into schema1.table1 (select * from schema2.table2);
```

This will insert all rows from `schema2.table2` to `schema1.table1`

Comment: Parentheses not needed, but +1 anyway !!!